# Signed number representations in verilog

Tags: numbers, verilog, digital-logic

1. What methods exist for signed number representation?
2. How do you know which signed number representation is used for the application?

e.g.

IEEE 754 allows you to represent 1.3444E-15  and  1.3444E+15... implying very large number & a very small number simply based on 1 signed representation of exponent.  IEEE 754 exponent [field uses *biased exponent representation*](http://www.slideshare.net/prochwani95/06-floating-point) see page 7. Similarly , which other methods exist.

Comment: for the first one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

Comment: IEEE-754 is a floating-point standard, not integer

Answer (score 0):

For Verilog, integers use 2's complement. Real numberes use IEEE-754. This is for declaring constants that you use to initialize a reg or assign to a wire and for built-in operands. Actual regs/wires are only a bunch of bits, and it's your design which determines what format numbers are stored with.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the types. Just use bit vector and interpret the bits as float.

```
wire unsigned [31:0] bits;
wire unsigned sign;
wire unsigned [7:0] exp;
wire unsigned [22:0] mantissa;

assign sign = bits[31];
assign exp = bits[30:23];
assign matissa = bits[22:0];
```